# Reducing vertical margin, increasing the top margin in the cell and centring the elements in the cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, cell

In the code I am using,

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % stretching row height

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rot{\multicolumn{1}{R{30}{0.1em}}}% no optional argument here, please!

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [!t]
    \caption{Summary}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ K{5mm} | K{15mm} | K{15mm} || K{8mm} | K{8mm}| K{8mm}| K{8mm} | K{8mm} }
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{No.} & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Case} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Value} \\ \cline{2-8}
        & X & Y & \rot{Column 1} & \rot{Column 2} & \rot{Column 3} & \rot{Column 4} & \rot{Column 5} \\ \hline \hline
        1 & \multirow{4}{=}{\centering 1} & a & \cite{HouMay19} &  &  & \cite{ZhuOct18}, \cite{HouMay19}  &  \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
        2 & & b & \cite{HouMay19} &  &  & \cite{HouMay19}  & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
        3 & & c & \cite{DouAug23} &  &  &  & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}
        4 & & d &  &  &  &  &   \\ \cline{1-8}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I would like to do few things to improve it:

1. First, how to reduce vertical cell margin so that a value could fit
   in one line
2. Secondly, how to increase the top margin so that there
   is the same space between the top and bottom text.
3. Finally, centre
   elements in the cell. The 'Column X' is rotated, and somehow LaTeX
   did not adjust the \multicolumn for the cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get a similar table using the [`tabularray` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for rotating the text
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Summary}
        \label{tab:summary}
        \begin{tblr}{
            vlines, hlines,
            stretch=1.5,
            colspec={m{5mm}m{15mm}m{15mm}*{5}{m{10mm}}},
            cells = {c},
            cell{2}{4-8} = {cmd={\rotatebox[origin=c]{60}}},
            % row{2} = {abovesep+=2pt, belowsep+=2pt}, % if you want more spaces around the second row
            vline{5-8}={2}{0pt},
        }
            \SetCell[r=2]{m, c} No. & \SetCell[c=2]{m, c} Case && \SetCell[c=5]{m, c} Value&&\\
             &X&Y&Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5\\
             1 & \SetCell[r=4]{m, c} 1 & a & cite1 &&& cite1, cite2 & \\
             2 & & b & cite1 &&& cite3 & \\
             3 & & c & cite1 &&& cite3 & \\
             4 & & d & cite1 &&& cite3 & \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In `tabularray`, the equivalent to `multirow` and `multicolumn` commands is the `SetCell` command.

Edit: I don't understand your first point, so I am not sure if that was addressed properly in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help Imran. The first point was: can I reduce the cell margin so that cite1 and cite2 can be in one line? All without increasing the column width.

Comment: @mikebuba By cell margin, do you mean horizontal space to both sides of the column? If yes, you may play with the `colsep` key of the columns. For reference, take a look at page 21 of the `tabularray` [documentation](https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf).

Comment: thanks @Imran. it worked great :) I defined `\SetTblrInner{rowsep=2pt,colsep=0pt}` before `\begin{tblr}{` and then set `colspec={m{5mm+12pt}m{15mm+12pt}m{15mm+12pt}*{5}{m{10mm+12pt}}},`